# Failed to obtain name info for:[(1*.*.**.***,"name or service not known"),(1*.*.**.***,"name or service not known"),

Tags: mongodb, hostname

```
016-03-07T09:10:16.992-0600 W NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain name info for: [ (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known"), (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known"), (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known") ]
2016-03-07T09:25:17.041-0600 W NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain name info for: [ (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known"), (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known"), (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known") ]
2016-03-07T09:40:17.085-0600 W NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain name info for: [ (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known"), (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known"), (1*.*.**.***, "Name or service not known") ]
```

1*.*.**.*** : is my IP Address

My Cluster is 3 node replica set Buit with MongoDB 3.2.

i never seen this kind of errors logging in my other environments.

what might be issue causing this.

Comment: this looks clunky, please specify technology and client settings

Comment: this is related to MongoDB

Comment: yes this is related to mongodb

Comment: This issue is from Os level host file,as IPV6 is disabled .so modified hostfile accordingly without IPV6 config on host file.now it works without any failed events.

Comment: reverse lookup of dns is not passing thorough which had been configured using pointer .

Comment: I encountered the same problem on Microsoft Azure. It looks like our cluster is loosing connection between some servers from time to time. As a result i get `{ "code" : 50, "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Operation timed out" }` for commands such as `sh.shardCollection`, `db.count` (for large collections > 1 billion docs) and have problem during balancing `Last reported error:  could not get updated shard list from config server due to ExceededTimeLimit Operation timed out`

Any luck fixing the problem?

Comment: i will try look into your issue ..

Comment: any luck with finding a solution here?

Comment: This is IPV6 issue ... where reverse lookup of dns is being failed in firewall ..

Answer (score 1):

Answer is very simple, node cannot resolve name from IP address.
Please add those addresses and correlating names to: /etc/hosts -file

```
12.345.678.90  node1  node1.my.domain
12.345.678.91  node2  node2.my.domain
```